# Repeat Excel row based on repeating 'n' records

Tags: excel

This is an example of my file now:

[image: Color scheme is just for ease]

And what I'm looking to get to:

[image: Color scheme is still just for ease's]

(Color scheme is still just for ease)

I can get the the Receipt and Amount to repeat for an Account when there's only one account but sometimes there's two, three, four, etc Accounts.

So I need to take the entire row where there's a receipt and paste it as many times as the count for an Account. Also an account can be listed multiple times so I can't do a COUNTIF based on Account name.

I need to do this for a couple other columns so I'm looking for a little help with just the Receipts that I can make changes to and apply it to the other columns.

Comment: Are you looking for a VBA solution or formulas? What have you tried so far?

Comment: just  remember, if your question is answered sufficiently, please check it as the 'answer' :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether this is a regular thing or not. The easiest way is to use a formula in a column to the right, which could then be cut-paste values over the top. Such a formula might be:

```
=if(A2<>"",A2,D1) 'if the receipt value is not blank, take it, otherwise take the last value
```

If you wanted to do this regularly, then some vba would be the way to go, something like:

```
Sub fillTheGaps()

For Each cell In Selection
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        cell.Value = cell.Offset(-1, 0)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Put this sub in a module, perhaps add a shortcut key for it. Select the data where you need to fill the gaps and run the macro.

Comment: The macro worked. I haven't used VBA in years and it clicked when I saw it. Thank you so much.